# VBScript won't move some files

Tags: windows, file, vbscript, move

I have written a VBScript that helps me organise my desktop every time it gets messy.

It works fine it moves my files and shortcuts based on the extension and the name of the app. However, I have a few app shortcut links that just won't move. in fact the vbs script will not even see them with this basic script

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
dir = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(dir)
Set files = folder.Files

For Each file in files
    MsgBox file.Name
Next
```

The files in question are all shortcuts they are iTunes, VLC, Google Chrome and WinRar.

Is there anything I can check to see why vbs won't even see these files?

Comment: Are you certain the files are actually there? Do you see them when you run `dir` in a Command Prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What You can see on your desktop is hybrid view of two folders:

> C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop
>
> C:\Users\Public\Desktop

Where the Public one is usually a place, where shortcuts are being created during app install, so all users do have them. In your script You are only looking for files in the YourUserName\Desktop, that's why the script does not see those shortcuts.

Comment: Thank You this solved the issue.
I should of realised this after working  for a schools IT team XD